# Creating mailbox file: File exists

Tags: redhat

I added user through command

```
adduser satya
```

I deleted the same user by

```
userdel satya
```

WhenI tried adding again

```
useradd satya
```

getting the following error:

> Creating mailbox file: File exists

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Used     `userdel -r satya`
 for deleting the user, it deleted the mail box too.

Now `useradd satya` created the user.

Comment: Works smoothly!

Answer (score 3):

That is because of *how* you delete a user.

- `useradd username` - adds a new user *username*;
- `[sudo] userdel username` - removes a user *username* leaving intact its files, namely its $HOME directory (`/home/username`). This is useful when you want to temporarily deactivate a particular user. Now, in some Linux environments (apparently in yours too), mailbox file is under a $HOME directory and that is why, in your case, it did not get deleted;
- `[sudo] userdel -r username` - removes a user *username* and recursively wipes out everything associated with this user (i.e. its $HOME directory).

`[x]` denotes `x` being optional.